# blur/hide label on focus

Tags: jquery, forms, focus, hide, blur

I have this client form (coded by others) that I can't change -

```
<p class="postal">
    <label for="postalcode">post code</label>
    <input id="postalcode" name="postalcode" type="text" value=""/>
</p>
```

The existing CSS dictates that the label is set 'within' the input. 
So I need to blur/hide the label.

I've 'guessed' that this markup would work, but alas it doesn't.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#postalcode').focus(function() {
       $('label').val('');
    });
});
```

I can't change either the CSS or the HTML which I'm sure ateotd would be easier.

Is this possible w/ jQuery?

EDIT:

Thanks for all the answers, you lot rock! I mis-worded my query I wanted the text of the label to be hidden/cleared not the whole label. So I've 'ticked' the answer that works.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parent `.postal` of current object

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Eay4q/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#postalcode').focus(function() {
       $(this).prev('label').text('');
    });
});
```

Comment: I didn't explain it well and this is what I needed, for the label's text to be removed not the label to be actually hidden.

Answer (score 1):

A label does'nt have a value, it has text content, but why not just hide the previous label when the input is focused :

```
$(function() {
    $('#postalcode').on('focus', function() {
       $(this).prev('label').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will hide the label on focus and will show it back on blur:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#postalcode').focus(function () {
        $(this).prev('label').hide();
    })
    .blur(function () {
        $(this).prev('label').show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MhLsU/

You can make it more universal if you use classes:

```
$('.field input').focus(function () {
    $(this).prev('label').hide();
})
.blur(function () {
    $(this).prev('label').show();
});
```

with HTML:

```
<p class="postal field">
    <label for="postalcode">post code</label>
    <input id="postalcode" name="postalcode" type="text" value="" />
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MhLsU/1/

Now it works not only for `postalcode`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide the label

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#postalcode').focus(function(){$('label').hide();});
});
```